# Ookii VistaFolderBrowserDialog and getting selected folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dialog, ookii

I am trying to use the [Ookii dialog pack](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) to spawn the new Vista style folder selection dialog.  That all works with this simple code:

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.StoreFolder;
dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

However, I cannot see any way of knowing when the user has selected a folder as there are no events on this object.  I could poll for changes in `SelectedPath`, but that seems a terribly inefficient way of doing things.

Is there some generic C# trick I have missed to enable me to know when a user has selected a folder and therefore update other fields appropriately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.SelectedPath = Properties.Settings.Default.StoreFolder;
dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = dlg.SelectedPath;
}
```

Comment: I was so wrapped up in looking for an event, that I didn't consider the possibility that it might just return a value... thanks!

Comment: This does not work (cannot compare bool? with DialogResult)

Comment: Should be: 'if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)'

Comment: @Everyone The last community edit changed it to compare with WinForms `DialogResult`, which is incorrect here because `ShowDialog()` indeed returns `bool?` when using `Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.VistaFolderBrowserDialog`(question is tagged WPF). Use either `if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)` or `if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)`.

Answer (score -1):

This answer uses Ookii.Dialogs.WPF NuGet package you can install from right inside visual studio. At the top left click Project -> Manage NuGet Packages... -> Go to browse tab and search OOkii.Dialogs.Wpf then install it. Now this code will work. :)

You can directly copy paste this.

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog(); //This starts folder selection using Ookii.Dialogs.WPF NuGet Package
FolderSelect.Description = "Please select the folder"; //This sets a description to help remind the user what their looking for.
FolderSelect.UseDescriptionForTitle = true;    //This enables the description to appear.        
if ((bool)FolderSelect.ShowDialog(this)) //This triggers the folder selection screen, and if the user does not cancel out...
{                
    TextBoxGameFolder.Text = FolderSelect.SelectedPath; //...then this happens.
}
```

Comment: Do not comment about the answer in the answer itself. Please avoid meta-commentary.